# Refrigerator making strange sound every few minutes

Tags: electrical, plumbing, refrigerator, kitchens

Forgive my description of the sound but it's all I can think of to describe it. Every few minutes, I hear a very very faint sound that sounds like what you'd expect to hear when someone is being electrocuted in the electric chair. It's very faint and near impossible to find out where it's coming from inside the fridge. The sound stops with a single "click" sound.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my fridge had exactly the same problem and it turned out to be a failing relay. this relay was part of a safety recall because when it failed, it was possible for it to catch fire.

please call your manufacturer and find out if this is the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the ice-maker has been accidentally turned on when there is no water going to it?

Comment: My first guess as well and easy to check.  Just turn it off and see if the noise goes away.  Line could be frozen, clogged, leaking, all sorts of different ways the ice maker can just stop working correctly.  I'm not sure it would be "impossible" to locate from inside the fridge though...

Comment: I just lifted the lever that is supposed to put the ice maker in "off" mode and I am still hearing the sound.  I guess we can rule that out.